# Javascript, jQuery.extend and "new"

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

I have a strange behavior while extending a prototype of an object using jQuery.extend.

Assuming this sample class:

```
var SampleClass = function (anArray) { this.Init(anArray); };

$.extend(SampleClass.prototype, {

    array: null,
    collection: new Array(),

    Init: function (arr) {
        var c = this;
        c.array = arr;
        c.insertInCollection();
    },

    insertInCollection: function () {

        var c = this;
        var l = c.array.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var bar = {};
            c.collection.push(bar);
        }

        alert(c.collection.length);
    }
});
```

Then I execute this sample code

```
var arr1 = [{ name: 'foo', value: 20 }, { name: 'baz', value: 20}];
var arr2 = [{ name: 'bar', value: 60 }, { name: 'gaz', value: 40}];

c = new SampleClass(arr1);
d = new SampleClass(arr2); //<-- HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
```

When I create the object "c", the collection gets populated inside the "insertInCollection" function, and the alert returns a length of 2.
However, when I instantiate the object "d" (doing a new TestClass(arr2)), the alert inside the "insertInCollection" function is fired and the alert shows 4!

In practice, I can't get what happens in the background. Seems like the elements of the first collection are never deleted - when the second object ("d") is created, it already has the 2 elements of the object "c" existing inside the "collection" property.

This also happens without using jQuery.extend, using the plain .prototype approach.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's "TestClass"? Right now you're appending to `SampleClass.prototype.array` and not an individual property of the instance.

Comment: Sorry, it was SampleClass instead of TestClass, now I edited. I kinda got what you're saying though - and was my guess after a couple of tries here and there. If you want to elaborate I'd gladly accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because every "instance" of `SampleClass` is sharing one `collection` property: when the `insertInCollection()` method accesses the object's `collection` property, none is found on the object itself so it uses the `collection` property of the object's prototype. To fix this, you need to create a new `collection` array for each `SampleClass` object. The `Init()` method would be a good place to do this:

```
Init: function (arr) {
    var c = this;
    c.collection = [];
    c.array = arr;
    c.insertInCollection();
},
```